# MS Access VBA set Chart Series data labels to true

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm creating a Chart with VBA and want to set the Data Labels to `true` among a few other things but I am unable to access the `Series` of my Chart. I've tried everything I found on google but nothing seems to work.
This is my current code

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim chartData As String
    Dim chartTitle As String
    Dim eanValue As String
    
        
    ' Get 'EAN' from form field
    eanValue = Me.EAN.Value
    ' Define the SQL query to calculate the sum of daily adjustments
    strSQL = "SELECT Format([AdjDate], 'DDDDD') AS DayFormatted, Sum([Adjustment]) AS [Adjustments] " & _
             "FROM adj_logs " & _
             "WHERE EAN = " & eanValue & " " & _
             "GROUP BY Format([AdjDate], 'DDDDD'), Int([AdjDate]) " & _
             "ORDER BY Int([AdjDate]);"

    ' Execute the query
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    
    ' Set the chart title
    chartTitle = "Total Daily Adjustments"
    
    ' Populate the chart
    Me.Chart47.RowSource = strSQL
    Me.Chart47.chartTitle = chartTitle

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Chart47.ChartSeriesCollection(1).DisplayDataLabel = True` ?